# 2022 Graduation Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

Coffee Stack Exchange graduated late last year. After discussing with the current moderators and the community management team, we're looking at scheduling the graduation election to start somewhere in October of 2022. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, we’re posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position. As mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in October '22.

Since post-beta elections need to be competitive, the interest check will help us determine how many slots we should have. To run a three slot election, we would need at least four candidates.

The winners of the graduation election will make up the new moderation team. As [then community manager Jon Ericson wrote in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections#comment1030478_314459):

> On graduation, all moderators must stand for re-election if they wish to continue in the role. There will be no difference between moderators who ran for an election during beta and moderators we appoint.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 2):

Without further ado:

I am planning to run again, hoping that the community will renew my diamond from the beta days.

Answer (score 2):

I plan on running again as well.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would run in an October election.